# check changes in consecutive elements (i.e columns) by row ignoring NAs in a data frame

Tags: r, match, row, apply

I´m trying to check if the elements in a given row are different.

As example,

```
> s <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=10, nrow=3, 
+                            c(0,NA,NA,1,1,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,0,1,1,NA,NA,NA), byrow = TRUE))

> s
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  0 NA NA  1  1 NA  0 NA NA  NA
2 NA NA  0 NA  0  0 NA NA  0   0
3 NA NA  0  0  0  1  1 NA NA  NA
```

This is my data frame and I would like to see if there are any changes from "0" to "1" **in consecutive columns by row** ignoring NA values. The output should be for example a vector `v <-c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE")` for the given example. Is there any simple solution?

Comment: Please add wanted output for given example data; also is it list, data.frame or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you actually care about whether the sequence `0:1` is present, not just whether there's a non-zero difference, you can do

```
library(zoo)
apply(s, 1, function(x) 'TRUE' %in% rollapply(x[!is.na(x)], 2, all.equal, 0:1, 
                                              check.attributes = F))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

To illustrate what I mean:

```
s[2,5] <- -1
apply(s, 1, function(x) any(diff(x[!is.na(x)]) != 0)) # Rui
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
apply(s, 1, function(x) 'TRUE' %in% rollapply(x[!is.na(x)], 2, all.equal, 0:1, 
                                              check.attributes = F))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: or this variation:  `apply(rollapply(na.locf(unname(t(s)), na.rm = FALSE), 2, identical, c(0, 1)), 2, any)`

Answer (score 1):

The following does what you describe.

```
v <- apply(s, 1, function(x) any(diff(x[!is.na(x)]) != 0))
v
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method that pastes the values together after dropping missing values, and then uses `grepl` to search for "01" in the resulting string.

```
apply(t(s), 2,
      function(x) grepl("01", paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse=""), fixed=TRUE))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Note that I transposed your dataset because column-wise operations tend to be more efficient, though it probably doesn't matter here.

Comment: Good method, faster than mine regardless of the transpose. I'm curious though, is it true that column-wise operations are more efficient for matrices? I had always assumed that was only true of data frames.

Comment: They tend to be a bit faster, though the difference is not as striking as with data.frames (versus row-wise operations). The reason for matrices is that the underlying data is stored as a vector with adjacent values laid out in in columns. (This is sometimes referred to as Fortran-style array storage or column dominant storage).